Make a slope-aspect map and create a circular legend for it in QGIS
I'm working on Terrain analysis of my ROI and could compute aspect and slope separately. Although I found a fairly easy tutorial on how to make a slope-aspect raster, I want to know if it's possible to have a circular legend like the one in the picture below. In ArcGIS, there's a tool that does it all but is there an extension that does it in QGIS?

